# Skip change detection on change in parent pom.xml property When using gitflow-incremental-builder

Tags: git, maven-plugin, incremental-build

I have multimodule maven project ,I have used gitflow-incremental-builder https://github.com/gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder to build only module which are changed . we increment version in parent pom.xml every time we create PR for any task or issue, so whenever there is change in parent pom.xml it builds all it's child module .one thing i do  can is to exclude parent pom.xml file using gib.excludePathsMatching provided by gitflow-incremental-builder  but i only want to exclude if version property is changed in parent pom.xml not on any other change in pom.xml. is there any way to do it